# Can this set tuple function be simplified

Tags: set-theory

I have a tuple $(a,b)$ b is real number. also k set contain $(a,b)$ tuples.
I need sum all a's b, that are equal.

for example say

$k = \{(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),(a_3,b_3),(a_4,b_4),(a_5,b_5),(a_6,b_6)(a_7,b_7)\}$

$a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = x$ and $ a_4 = a_5 = a_6 = y$ then

$O = \{ (x,b_1 + b_2 + b_3),(y,b_4 + b_5 + b_6),(a_7,b_7) \} $

it feel like union for a's but sum for b's. is there other simpler way to express this function using notation and what not

Comment: The second tuple of your $O$ doesnt make sense. It should be $(y,b_4+b_5+b_6)$.

Comment: I will edit it. sorry

Comment: The fact that the $a$
's are sets is irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: $$O=\left\{(u,v)\;\left|\;\exists b,(u,b)\in k\text{ and }v=\sum_{(u,b)\in k}b\right.\right\}.$$ If that doesn't answer your question, can you please be more specific?

Comment: Since we don't do any operation except equal using a .I suppose it is. so should I let it be an just an element ?

Comment: You don't need to specify anything about the $a$'s.